# what is the output of the regex_match in c++;

Tags: c++, regex

Hey I am learning the regex and I am confused why this expression return 0? It should return 1 as the string "zy" matches in my expression..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {

        string s2="ezyfo";
        bool result=regex_match(s2,regex("zy")) ;  
        cout<<result;                                    //output is 0 while "zy should match in the string s2
 
    return 0;
}
```

output is

```
0
```

Comment: I don't know this API, but if you use the patten `.*zy.*`, then [it works](https://rextester.com/MUN34394).

Comment: `"ezyfo" ≠ "zy"`

Comment: Just read the docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match. Specifically, "Note that `regex_match` will only successfully match a regular expression to an *entire* character sequence, whereas `std::regex_search` will successfully match subsequences."

Comment: why using only "zy" does not work  as it also match  in the s2 string..

Answer (score 0):

It should be like this. we need to format regex string correctly

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    string s2="ezyfo";
    regex match = regex("(.*)(zy)(.*)");
    bool result=regex_match(s2,match) ;
    cout<<result << endl;                             

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: what if I declared zy in seaparate string s2. How to should I provide arguement to regex?

Comment: @Sachin Use [`std::regex_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) as explained in my comment.

Comment: You can use char array to solve your problem
char regStr[] = "(.*)(zy)(.*)";
regex match = regex(regStr);

Comment: @BessieTheCow thanks it worked for me... but still I am not clear why my solution not matched the s2 string 

Comment: Because `regex_match` has to match the **entire** target string, not just part of it. What you are looking for is `regex_search`, as already explained (three times now).

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    std::string s2 = "ezyfo";
    std::regex match = std::regex("zy");
    bool result = std::regex_search(s2, match);
    std::cout << result << "\n";                             

 return 0;
}
```

Advantages compared to OP's implementation/other answers:

- No `.*` required before and after the text snipped we are searching for. As @BessieTheCow pointed out `std::regex_search` searches for a substring whereas `std::regex_match` tries to match the *entire* string ("zy" ≠ ezyfo).

Bonus (not directly related to your question):

- No `using namespace std;` - see [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).
- No `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` - see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h).
- No `std::endl` since flushing doesn't seem to be necessary here - see [C++: “std::endl” vs “\n”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/c-stdendl-vs-n).